# Why haven't I received the "Quick As A Flash" achievement?

Tags: 4-elements

I have managed to obtain all of the 4 Elements achievements except for one: "Quick As A Flash".

The description reads, "Complete the quest in 90 seconds or less".

Which quest?  I'm pretty sure finishing the entire game in 90 seconds is impossible, and I've finished a number of levels in well less than 90 seconds without obtaining the badge.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed Playrix (the game's developer) and they said that in order to get this achievement,

> You need to complete the level in 90 seconds or less and you will get the achievement.

I don't know why you haven't gotten it if you have indeed completed levels in under that time as you said in your question, because according to them, it should have popped.

Comment: Do you know if it keeps trying to activate?  It might be something silly like "My 'net went out the first time, and it never bothers to send the 'You've earned it!' message to Steam again" or something...

Comment: That might be it.

Answer (score 2):

"The Quest" means the Hidden Object puzzles you have to solve to open the books.

If you could de-activate the fairy, the first one would obviously be the easiest and, more importantly, the easiest to re-start. Unfortunately, the game saves each object part you find instantly. And since the fairy talks too slow at the beginning, you have to do this achievement on one of the later three.
It's best to backup your savegame file after you've done all 16 levels of a book plus the four Spot the Difference puzzles. It's an .XML file located [under Vista/7] at **C:\ProgramData\Playrix Entertainment** [or use **Start** | **Run** | **%AllUsersProfile%\Playrix Entertainment**].

The achievement should unlock the moment the key appears [i.e. you used the last of the four items with the last "combinable" area of the puzzle].